# get all coordinates between location for iphone Map Kit

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit, latitude-longitude

Can anyone tell me how to get all Lat,Long values between to locations...???
As part of implementation I would like to have all the Lat,Long values between the start end end point to draw the route.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: First, allocate a buffer with room for aleph_0 coordinate pairs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "all"?  Since lat/long pairs are doubles, you are talking about an infinite number of points.

If you want to draw a line between two points you can use a CAShapeLayer to draw a line on the map to connect them.

The word "route" however impies you want to know points that travel along a road.  There again, what are you really asking for?  Routes people could drive?  Walk?  Take a bus?  MapKit itself does not help you with routing at all, you would have to look at other third party frameworks.

Comment: Since that link explains how to draw a route on a map, I'm guessing you really want a routing engine - you're going to have to look at an SDK like CloudMade:  http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/routing-http-api

Comment: Waah ...!!! This is awesome ..!!!! I just tok a quick glance at it...I should be able to get the task accomplished. Thanks a ton...!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Finding the points is pretty straightforward and doesn't require any clever trigonometry. Note that if the distance between points needs to be a specific amount -- say every 100 meters -- then trigonometry will be required. We'll do the simple version, though.

Basically you figure out the difference between the latitudes and the difference between the longitudes, decide how many points you want (as noted, "all" is an infinite number), divide the distance by the number of points, and iterate through them. (Note: I haven't tested this code, but you should be able to get the idea.)

```
// Making my own names for your start and stop coordinate, use your own
CLLocationCoordinate2D startPoint; // Your starting latitude and longitude
CLLocationCoordinate2D stopPoint;  // Ending latitude and longitude

CLLocationCoordinate2D newPoint;   // A newly-created point along the line

double latitudeModifier;    // Distance to add/subtract to each latitude point
double longitudeModifier;   // Distance to add/subtract to each longitude point

int numberOfPoints = 100;   // The number of points you want between the two points

// Determine the distance between the lats and divide by numberOfPoints
latitudeModifier = (startPoint.latitude - endPoint.latitude) / numbernumberOfPoints;
// Same with lons
longitudeModifier = (startPoint.longitude - endPoint.longitude) / numbernumberOfPoints;

// Loop through the points
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
    newPoint.latitude = startPoint.latitude + (latitudeModifier * i);
    newPoint.longitude = startPoint.longitude + (longitudeModifier * i);

    // Do something with your newPoint here

}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. The code worked fine for getting the required values. But unfortunately  it does not do what I wanted to accomplish.

The resulting points will draw a straight line between start and end point. In the example  spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65 , curved lines are drawn since the lat,long values for all the curved locations were available. Any idea how I can get to draw curved lines/route map ….???? Greatly appreciate your effort in helping me with this issue…!!!!

Comment: Ah, thought you were referring to a straight line. You can get actual road routes via the Google Maps API. You send it your start and destination and it sends you the complete route, step-by-step, with both the lat/long pairs for each stop (and for curved roads, etc.) as well as the driving or walking directions. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: @MatthewFrederick sir..Can you help me in details...regarding getting all coordinate points between source address to destination address.